# Efficient Way to Read SAS file with over 100 million rows into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I have an SAS file that is roughly 112 million rows. I do not actually have access to SAS software, so I need to get this data into, preferably, a pandas DataFrame or something very similar in the python family. I just don't know how to do this efficiently. *ie*, just doing `df = pd.read_sas(filename.sas7bdat)` takes a few hours. I can do chunk sizes but that doesn't really solve the underlying problem. Is there any faster way to get this into pandas, or do I just have to eat the multi-hour wait? Additionally, even when I have read in the file, I can barely do anything with it because iterating over the df takes forever as well. It usually just ends up crashing the Jupyter kernel. Thanks in advance for any advice in this regard!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part, I guess there is not much to do as the `read_sas` options are limited.

For the second part 1. iterating manually through rows is slow and not pandas philosophy. Whenever possible use vectorial operations. 2. Try to look into specialized solutions for large datasets, like [dask](https://dask.org/). Also read [how to scale to large dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html).

Comment: Appreciate your response. Are you aware of anyway to store a pandas df for repeated use? Basically, so I don't have to read in the same massive file every single time I restart the kernel, and I could just have the df ready to go. Thanks

Comment: I never compared myself, but you can read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need your entire file to work on it so you can take 10%. You can also change your variable types to reduce its memory.

- if you want to store a df and re use it instead of re importing the entire file each time you want to work on it you can save it as a pickle file (.pkl) and re open it by using `pandas.read_pickle`